# Perl regex - match variable next to digit

Tags: regex, perl

I want to suffix a group match with a digit in a rexeg replace expression. How do I separate the match variable from the actal digit?

If I want

```
hello 55 friends -> hello 551 friend
i am 29 happy -> i am 291 happy
```

I tried with

```
s/([0-9]+)/$11/g;
```

But if I put a `1` directly after `$1`, perl interprets it as `$11`(rightfully so). In bash, I could have written `${1}1`, but this doesn't seem to work in perl.

EDIT: Turns out that @toolic was right, s/([0-9]+)/${1}1/g; does work, I had an escaping issue with my shell. If you post that answer as a proper answer I'll accept it! Thanks

Comment: `$val=~s/([0-9]+)/$1.1/eg;`

Comment: This: `echo 'hello 55 friends\ni am 29 happy' | perl -ne 's/([0-9]+)/${1}1/; print'` outputs this: `hello 551 friends
i am 291 happy` in my Perl

Comment: Turns out that @toolic was right, `s/([0-9]+)/${1}1/g;` does work, I had an escaping issue with my shell. If you post that answer as a proper answer I'll accept it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the optional curly braces for backreferences (e.g. `${1}` instead of `$1`) does work in perl.

**[Demo here](https://www.regex101.com/r/99kYD7/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex : `(\d+)` and replace capture group with suffix 1

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kzf2yq/1)

Example :

```
<?php
$string = 'hello 55 friends i am 29 happ';
$pattern = '/(\d+)/';
$replacement = '${1}1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```